# Splitting strings in C strtok()

Tags: c, string, split, strtok

I want to split strings received from the terminal input, if they are contained on a buffer. If they are I want to print them.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* fich[5]={"ha","he","hi","ho","hu"};

int main(){

char passaarg[70];
const char space[2]= " ";
char *token;
int i;

while(1){

    read(STDIN_FILENO, passaarg, 70);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(strncmp(passaarg, fich[i], 2) == 0){
            token = strtok(passaarg, space);
            while(token != NULL){
                printf("%s\n", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, space);
                printf("%s\n", token);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

My output is the following one:

```
ha he
ha
he

he

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your second `printf` will eventually try to print a `NULL` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
token = strtok(passaarg, space);
while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, space);
    printf("%s\n", token);
}
```

That second `printf` will cause undefined behavior (likely a crash) when `strtok` returns `NULL`, as it will when there are no more tokens in the string. Just remove that line.

Stylistically, I'd use a `for` loop here:

```
for(token = strtok(passaarg, space); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, space)) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I always prefer the for-loop construct with `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }
```

The while loop will fail when the token is `NULL`. At this time you are trying to print this pointer using your second `printf()` in the while loop which will lead to undefined behavior.

Get rid of your second `printf()`